# Non-decreasing Convex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

When my textbook states, "Non Decreasing Convex Function", does it mean that the function is convex and increases in y for every x from its minimum? That is if f(x) = y is convex.

Please explain if I am wrong, and what information does this give in Optimization?

Comment: A constant function is non decreasing and convex.

Comment: It just means that the function is convex and is not decreasing..

Comment: For example, $f(x)=e^x$ is convex and increasing, which means it is also nondecreasing. The function $g(x)=\max\{x,0\}$ is convex and nondecreasing, but it is *not* increasing because it is constant  for $x\leq 0$.